# How are you supposed to use text editors without debugging tools?

Tags: ide, text-editor

The thing I haven't been able to understand is how I am supposed to use a plain ol' text editor like TextWrangler or Atom to code, as opposed to a full-blow IDE like Xcode or Visual Studio. There are no debugging tools, so you can't know if you made an error, and their isn't autocomplete (prebugging, heh heh) which makes it much easier to make mistakes. I feel like I am missing something; how do people debug with their text editor workflow?

Comment: http://9gag.com/gag/4088277/real-programmers-code-in-binary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a text editor without debug tools forces you to write beautiful code that works first time 100% of the time. Each line of code is carefully crafted and does exactly what you expect it to do.

I personally use VIM for all my programming, it takes a while to learn but it's definitely worth it.
You end up writing code which is easy to read, because you have to read and re-read you code before you run it.
Debugging is more than just pressing a button and someone else software tells you whats wrong with yours. It's about deeply understanding your code and exactly what it is doing. I'll admit that sometimes finding a missing comma can be a pain, but the tradeoff is definitely worth it.

At the end of the day it depends on whether you just want to turn out 800 line of code an hour, or if you want to build software which is robust and easily extendable by anybody.

Comment: Your answer just got me out of my long search, am tired of Dreamweaver and needed something else that will give error-free coding. Encourage specialization. Now I have a directory of where to go

Comment: Writing beautiful code that works first time 100% of the time is a pipe dream. Your answer sounds like gospel or something, quite funny. Also, debugging isn't more than pressing a shortcut. With breakpoints (incl. conditional ones) and ability to inspect any variables or fields in the scope, or evaluate any arbitrary code not only at the breakpoint but also at any previous frame in the stack, it's undoubtedly useful. It's not that your answer is out-of-date in 2022. It was out of date in 2015, when these features already existed in many IDEs. Today they exist in lightweight text editors.

Answer (score 2):

Atom and almost all this ide VIM ...
their is a plugins https://atom.io/packages
You install what plugins that you want

I believe that this is the power of this editors. You decide what plugins you want.

For atom for example

linter https://atom.io/packages/linter is a tool for visualize errors.

autocomplete https://atom.io/packages/autocomplete is a tool for auto complete.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't quite understand what you are saying. Do you mean most text editors have support for debugging tools via plug ins?

Comment: I edited.. one sec I add more usefull packages for atom..
And yes this is what I say. You can Install what plugins you want

Comment: Yes, @popkernel. Install different  plug-ins to do whatever you want to to do.  They are not packed with the plug-ins.

Answer (score 0):

The only difference is you have to compile manually.
 
If the error happens at compile time, the compiler will tell you, otherwise you have to find & fix the error yourself.

For the auto-complete, it's still available in most text editors(Atom, notepad++ etc...), however it's not always as good as intellisense.